# How to get Output parameter of Mysql Store procedure using hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a MySql stored procedure which contains two input parameter (username and password) and one Output parameter (user status). I'm unable to get the Output parameter by using Hibernate 4 and I refer below link http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

Hiberanate Code

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL SP_Login_Authentication(:u_name,:p_word,:output)");
query.setParameter("u_name", username);  
query.setParameter("p_word", pwd);  
List return1 = query.list();
```

Stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `CP`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_Login_Authentication`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_Login_Authentication`(IN u_name VARCHAR(255),IN p_word VARCHAR(255),OUT output INT )
BEGIN 
DECLARE user1 INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE password1 INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE status1 INT ;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO user1
FROM users WHERE user_name=u_name;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PASSWORD) INTO password1
FROM users WHERE PASSWORD=p_word;
SET status1=(SELECT STATUS FROM users WHERE PASSWORD=p_word AND user_name=u_name);
IF(user1 = 0) THEN
SET output = -3;
ELSEIF (user1 = 1 AND password1 = 0) THEN
SET output = -2;
ELSEIF (user1 = 1 AND password1 = 1 AND status1=1 ) THEN
SET output = 1;
ELSEIF (user1 = 1 AND password1 = 1 AND status1=0 ) THEN
SET output = 0;
ELSEIF (user1 = 1 AND password1 = 1 AND status1=-1 ) THEN
SET output =-1;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you update Store procedures?

Comment: hi ashok ... updated my Question u can look into it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy), as I described in [this post](http://vladmihalcea.com/taming-jpa-with-the-sql-statement-count-validator/).

Assuming your application expects a "dataSource" @Resource this is how you can configure the ttddyy proxy:

```
<bean id="testDataSource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource" init-method="init"
  destroy-method="close">
    <property name="className" value="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource"/>
    <property name="uniqueName" value="testDataSource"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="0"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="allowLocalTransactions" value="false" />
    <property name="driverProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
            <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="driverClassName">${jdbc.driverClassName}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="proxyDataSource" class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.support.ProxyDataSource">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="testDataSource"/>
    <property name="listener">
        <bean class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.ChainListener">
            <property name="listeners">
                <list>
                    <bean class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.CommonsQueryLoggingListener">
                        <property name="logLevel" value="INFO"/>
                    </bean>
                    <bean class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.DataSourceQueryCountListener"/>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<alias name="proxyDataSource" alias="dataSource"/>
```

Now the Hibernate output vs datasource-proxy:

```
INFO  [main]: o.v.s.i.WarehouseProductInfoServiceImpl - newWarehouseProductInfo
Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_6_, company0_.name as name2_6_ from Company company0_
INFO  [main]: n.t.d.l.CommonsQueryLoggingListener - Name:, Time:1, Num:1, Query:{[select company0_.id as id1_6_, company0_.name as name2_6_ from Company company0_][]}
Hibernate: insert into WarehouseProductInfo (id, quantity) values (default, ?)
INFO  [main]: n.t.d.l.CommonsQueryLoggingListener - Name:, Time:0, Num:1, Query:{[insert into WarehouseProductInfo (id, quantity) values (default, ?)][19]}
Hibernate: insert into Product (id, code, company_id, importer_id, name, version) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
INFO  [main]: n.t.d.l.CommonsQueryLoggingListener - Name:, Time:0, Num:1, Query:{[insert into Product (id, code, company_id, importer_id, name, version) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)][phoneCode,1,-5,Phone,0]}
```

The datasource-proxy queries contain parameter values and you can even add custom JDBC statement interceptors beside the default logging ones.

This works for any SQL query from SELECT statements to stored procedures.